# How can a jar file be created from a Univocity Parsers snapshot?

Tags: parsing, csv, jar

I would like to use the Univocity Parsers new functionality that is present in the 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.

I'm using IntelliJ, and am not using Maven, and currently have the univocity-parsers-1.5.6.jar present in project library, and would like to replace it with a jar created from the 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.

How can a jar file be created from a Univocity Parsers snapshot?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can just download the jar from maven central:

https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/univocity/univocity-parsers/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT

A new SNAPSHOT jar will be generated every time relevant features / bugfixes are applied.

If you want to build from the source code, run `mvn install` using the command line or from IntelliJ itself.